# Custom branding in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

How can I change look and feel of a SharePoint site in SharePoint online.  I want to be able to change the master page i.e remove left navigation and change layout and what is there in masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many articles and samples in the web that provide information on changing the UI of a Sharepoint site,
Below are some- >
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Change-look-and-feel-baff6052-436d-4065-953f-24612834fff5

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-look-of-your-SharePoint-site-06bbadc3-6b04-4a60-9d14-894f6a170818

You can have custom css files and do changes to master pages using the SharePoint designer which can be downloaded using the below link.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491

Still its preferred to go with out of the box themes as MS push updates to your sites which may break your customizations, even though there will be a notification in your Admin center it can only be seen by the admins and if the message is not passed it may break your customizations.